# Bootstrap 5 multiple cards in carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-cards

I'm using bootstrap 5 to create multiple cards in a carousel, but it just showing 1 card per slide, how can I make it so that it's showing 3 cards per slide?

Should I use row and columns ?

Or is there a way to combine bootstrap 4 and bootstrap 5 together ? because I tried using both of them and they're just crashing with each other.

this is the carousel code from bootstrap 5 that I have modified.

```
<div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="media-container">
                  <div class="course">
                    <div class="media-preview">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-info">
                      <h6 class="tanggalMedia1">20 MARET 2023</h6>
                      <h5 class="descBerita1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit <br> amet consectetu</h5>
                      <div class="btnRead">
                        <a href="#">&#8594;</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="media-container">
                  <div class="course">
                    <div class="media-preview">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-info">
                      <h6 class="tanggalMedia1">20 MARET 2023</h6>
                      <h5 class="descBerita1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit <br> amet consectetu</h5>
                      <div class="btnRead">
                        <a href="#">&#8594;</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="media-container">
                    <div class="course">
                      <div class="media-preview">
                      </div>
                      <div class="media-info">
                        <h6 class="tanggalMedia1">20 MARET 2023</h6>
                        <h5 class="descBerita1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit <br> amet consectetu</h5>
                        <div class="btnRead">
                          <a href="#">&#8594;</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-container">
                    <div class="course">
                      <div class="media-preview">
                      </div>
                      <div class="media-info">
                        <h6 class="tanggalMedia1">20 MARET 2023</h6>
                        <h5 class="descBerita1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit <br> amet consectetu</h5>
                        <div class="btnRead">
                          <a href="#">&#8594;</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div>
```

cdn script :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="false">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
     <div class="card-group">
      <div class="card">
       <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
       <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
       <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
       <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
<div class="card-group">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
  

<div class="card-group">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```